# Birchas Hatorah and Sefardic women

Tags: halacha, women, torah-study, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, birchos-hatorah

In [an earlier question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2194/759) I mentioned that women make Birchas Hatorah. Is the same true for Sefardic women and why?

Comment: Why would there be a difference between Ashkenazim and Sefardim in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halacha Berurah 47:27

> Women also say birkat hatorah every day because they're chayav to learn the laws that apply to them, for example hilchot Shabbat, tefillah, berachot, hilchot niddah and challah, and other halachot of issur and heter. In any event, they're not required to say birkat hatorah -- it's simply that if they want to, then they're permitted to.

Comment: @Gershon why not? Is it because I forgot to point out that Halacha Berurah is written by R' Ovadia Yosef's son, R' David Yosef?

Answer (score 1):

Bais Yosef Orach Chaim 47:14 - Women are Mechuyav in Birchas HaTorah

Yechave Da'as Chelek 3 Siman 72 page 230 says that we Pasken like this Bais Yosef.

Comment: I would appreciate a halacha lmasseh not the explanation like a Reb Ovadiah Yosef, Ben Ish Chai, or the Kaf Hachaim

Comment: the why was good too

Comment: There's a klal in hilchot berachot by Sephardim that when there's a machloket poskim about whether a beracha should be said, we paskin safek berachot l'hakel, even against the mechaber. Therefore quoting Maran Beit Yosef can't be the last word on this subject. (So see my other answer for something more contemporary.)

Comment: There does not seem to be any Machlokes here.

Comment: In general it is not always the Klal that all Sefardim Poskin like the Beis Yosef

Answer (score 0):

Women are obligated to say Birchas Hatorah.

Even though the position of the Shulchan Aruch is that women may not make berachos when performing mitzvahs they are not obligated in [like time bound mitzvahs], the Shulchan Aruch stills requires women to make the bracha.

Many (Beis Halevi, among others) explain why [Sephardic] women can make Birchas Hatorah because they are obligated to learn the laws relating to mitzvahs they are obligated in.

The Brisker Rav (Hil. Berachos) quotes his father, R' Chaim Solovetchik, that Birchas Hatorah is not a Birchas HaMitzvos, but actually a Beracha on the 'cheftza of Torah' (more similar in classification to Birchas Hashvach).

Comment: "they are obligated to learn the laws relating to mitzvahs they are obligated in" which when you think about it is probably around 90% of laws, as a very rough estimate

Comment: @Heshy: True. The chiddush is that although they have no Mitzvah of Talmud Torah in it's own rights, the fact that they are obligated to learn the laws practically relevant to them (i.e., they are not obligated to learn as an end of its own, but as a means to keep their other obligations) is enough to obligate a Birchas HaTorah.

Comment: I 100% agree in lomdus.  It just bothers me when schools use "girls don't have to learn" as an excuse for low quality education.  Sure, if the boys are learning Sukkah it's probably better for the girls to learn something else, but most topics apply to everyone.  You never know when an obscure halacha in Bava Metziah is going to be relevant on short notice when you don't have your phone on you.  Not to mention Zeraim, Kodshim, and Tahoros (no I don't mean Berachos and Niddah) - Mashiach could come at any moment and we'll all have to know those halachos.